# Primefaces wizard drops info from previous tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

I am new to JSF. I am trying to use the Wizard component from the Primefaces official site and I am facing an issue: when moving to next tab, the info from the previous gets dropped.
I used the code from the site except the User bean. When I did a debug I saw that every time the Next button is pushed, the setter for each field is called, but the fields that were set in the previous steps are null.
I am using primefaces 3.5 version and jsf-api and jsf-impl 2.1.18.

Here is the code:

UserWizard:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userWizardBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserWizard {

private User user = new User();
private boolean skip;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserWizard.class.getName());

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
   this.user = user;
}

public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    //Persist user

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Successful", "Welcome :" + user.getFirstname());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public boolean isSkip() {
    return skip;
}

public void setSkip(boolean skip) {
    this.skip = skip;
}

public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
    logger.info("Current wizard step:" + event.getOldStep());
    logger.info("Next step:" + event.getNewStep());

    if(skip) {
        skip = false;   //reset in case user goes back
        return "confirm";
    }
    else {
        return event.getNewStep();
    }
}

}
```

User:

```
public class User {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Integer age;
private String street;
private String city;
private String postalCode;
private String info;
private String email;
private String phone;

public User(String firstname, String lastname, Integer age, String street, String city, String postalCode, String info, String email, String phone) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.street = street;
    this.city = city;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.info = info;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public User() {

}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

And the xhtml file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form>

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz"
              flowListener="#{userWizard.onFlowProcess}">

        <p:tab id="personal" title="Personal">

            <p:panel header="Personal Details">

                <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
                    <h:outputText value="Firstname: *" />
                    <p:inputText required="true" label="Firstname"
                                 value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Lastname: *" />
                    <p:inputText required="true" label="Lastname"
                                 value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="address" title="Address">
            <p:panel header="Adress Details">

                <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Street: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.street}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Postal Code: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.postalCode}" />

                    <h:outputText value="City: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.city}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Skip to last: " />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{userWizard.skip}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="contact" title="Contact">
            <p:panel header="Contact Information">

                <h:messages errorClass="error"/>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
                    <h:outputText value="Email: *" />
                    <p:inputText required="true" label="Email"
                                 value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Phone: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.phone}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Additional Info: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userWizard.user.info}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="confirm" title="Confirmation">
            <p:panel header="Confirmation">

                <h:panelGrid id="confirmation" columns="6">
                    <h:outputText value="Firstname: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.firstname}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Lastname: " />
                    <h:outputText  styleClass="outputLabel"
                                   value="#{userWizard.user.lastname}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Age: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.age}" />>

                    <h:outputText value="Street: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.street}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Postal Code: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.postalCode}" />

                    <h:outputText value="City: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.city}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Email: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.email}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Phone " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.phone}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Info: " />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="outputLabel"
                                  value="#{userWizard.user.info}" />

                    <h:outputText />
                    <h:outputText />
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="growl"
                                 actionListener="#{userWizard.save}"/>

            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

    </p:wizard>

 </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Any help or tip would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I also tried  using '@ConversationScope' and '@ViewScope' but without any luck.

Comment: That works for me, the only thing I did is to change the name of the bean to `userWizard`, as you have in your xhtml, which I suppose it's a mistyping. With that change works like a charm.

Comment: I changed the name - still not working.

Comment: Check when user fields are getting null values again. Make some debug and see what's going on.

Comment: Hi. After a debug I saw that the constructor of the User bean is called: once at the beginning, once for each tab, and once when the data is submitted. This is why the information is dropped. Still, I don't know why it loads a new User bean every time.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to make it work: just added:
@ManagedBean(name = "userWizard")
and 
@ViewScoped 
to the UserWizard class and it worked .

Comment: Also make sure to clear the cache before any change in the output format of the xhtml file. Otherwise the problem described above will occur sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with the scope because you have mentioned as session scope so data is stored only for single session, it should be View scope as in view scope data remains stored unless you are redirected to another page.

I hope it helps you.